# Why is the file not showing up in request.files and in request.forms instead?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, fetch-api

I'm am trying to send a file from React to flask, but when I send it, it doesn't come up in request.files where it's supposed to be, and instead in request.form. How do I fix this?

here is react code:

```
  const data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    await fetch("/run", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.file))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }
```

here is the flask code:

```
@app.route('/run', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return {'file': "no file part"}
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return {'file': 'no selected file'}
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))

    else:
        return {"file": "this a get"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this works but here is the answer I found.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';

function App(){
  const [file, setFile] = useState("")
  const uploadInput = useRef()

  const fileValue = (ev) => setFile(ev.target.value)

  const handleUploadImage = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', uploadInput.current.files[0]);
    setFile("")
    fetch('/run', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    })
  }

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleUploadImage}>
        <input ref={uploadInput} value={file} type="file" onChange={fileValue}/>
        <button disabled={file === ""}>Submit</button>
      </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```